# What do you call the part of the food stand that displays the food?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

What do you call this type of food stand?

[image]

Like for using in a sentence:

> On the front, the [...] displayed all kinds of sushi.

Comment: refrigerator — I'd call anything like this at a butchers counter/ice-cream palour/delicatessen, etc. a display fridge (https://www.google.com/search?q=display+fridge&tbm=isch)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The items in the picture are arranged on *shelves*.  A *[shelf](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shelf#Noun)* is a  “A flat, rigid, rectangular structure, fixed at right angles to a wall, and used to support, store or display objects”.  Terms like *[tray](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tray#Noun_2)* and *[rack](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rack#Noun)* may also be appropriate for the shelves.

The whole structure is (as Mari-Lou mentioned) a display counter, but might also be called a *display case*, and if it had a glass front, a *[vitrine](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vitrine#Noun)*,  “A glass-paneled cabinet or case, especially for displaying articles such as china, objets d'art, or fine merchandise”.

To avoid used of *display* as a noun or adjective and as a verb, consider the verbs *held* and *arrayed*:

> At the front, a display case held all kinds of sushi.
>   At the front, all kinds of sushi were arrayed for sale.
>   All kinds of sushi were arrayed for sale on shelves beneath the counter.

Answer (score 3):

*A food display counter*

See [Google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=food+display+stands&client=firefox-a&hs=1nB&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=imibUs-ZLIas7QaZkoHIBw&ved=0CDoQsAQ&biw=1339&bih=588#q=%22food+display+counter%22&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&tbm=isch&imgdii=_). As to whether you should simply call it a *counter* I'd go for, "the store counter" or the "delicatessen counter" [images](https://www.google.com/search?q=delicatessen+counter&client=firefox-a&hs=ClW&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=rcs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=3mybUqL-FdLy7AaYrIDQBA&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1339&bih=588). You can't leave "counter" on its own, it becomes too generic. A counter is also the flat kitchen surface where you cook and prepare food.

As there are fish counters [<sup>1</sup>](http://www.internationalsupermarketnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/fish_counter.jpg), meat display counters; confectionery counters etc. You could call it a "sushi counter".

In this website the [display units](http://www.salepoint.co.uk/grocery-design.php?p=design) on sale are called *confectionery counters*.

Comment: so since I already have the word display in the sentence, maybe I can just call it *counter*?

Answer (score 2):

I would say it’s a display *case*.

> I walked up to the food stand & looked at what was for sale in the
>   *case*. Pickings were slim, but I did my best to find something that
>   would tide me over for the next few hours. Long night ahead.